# Facebook Login - Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains

Tags: facebook, oauth, facebook-oauth

I really have problem with Facebook. The old application don't require **Valid OAuth redirect URIs**, today, I have a problem with this app and remove it. I created again. I have two problem is:

- Facebook Login not accept http protocol (resolved).
- Facebook Login require **Valid OAuth redirect URIs** (current question)

My URL is: https://sharengay.com/anlink/

When click button Login it show error like:

> Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains

The URL when click button login is:
https://www.facebook.com/v2.10/dialog/oauth?client_id=2165341230417089&state=4bd285b45a9d3fdba98d894cb2fc7efc&response_type=code&sdk=php-sdk-5.5.0&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fsharengay.com%2Fanlink%2Flogin.php&scope=public_profile%2Cuser_friends

I was add in **Valid OAuth redirect URIs** is:

[image]

Sorry about language, I add three values:

https://sharengay.com/anlink

https://sharengay.com/

https://sharengay.com/anlink/layouts/Social/Connector/SocialLogin.ashx?type=access

I don't have experience with Facebook OAuth. I think I lost URL, so Facebook show this error.

Comment: You need to add the exact value the redirect_uri parameter has in your login dialog call as Valid OAuth Redirect URI. For the URL you have shown, that is `https://sharengay.com/anlink/login.php`

Comment: @CBroe I add your suggest link. It's show error like: Graph returned an error: Can't load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and sub-domains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.
And URl have structure look like: https://sharengay.com/anlink/login.php?code=&state=

Comment: If you get this error after Facebook has redirected back to your app, then that usually means that in the API call to exchange the code for a token, your system passes a different value for the redirect_uri parameter, than it did in the login dialog call - it has to be the exact same in both instances. So you’ll have to debug that.